# C# TCP client receive in localhost but not on the network

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

my c# client application talks with a server and, on localhost, all seems to work.
The problem is when I put the application on another PC: I see the TCP packets arriving on wireshark but my socket do nothing.
In this image the 9 bytes buffer is the server TX.

[image: Wireshark Screenshot]

PS. My anti virus and firewall are disabled.

What could be the problem?

Here the code (for brevity only RX methods)

```
public partial class CSocket
{

  private const int RX_BUFF_SIZE = 1024;

  private Socket _clientSkt;
  private byte[] _rx_buffer = new byte[RX_BUFF_SIZE];

  private MemoryStream _rx_stream = new MemoryStream();

  // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
  private static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);


  public bool Connect(string IP, int Port)
  {
    if (_clientSkt != null)
      if (_clientSkt.Connected) return true;

    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), Port);

    // Create a TCP/IP socket.
    _clientSkt = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    connectDone.Reset();
    // Connect to the remote endpoint.
    _clientSkt.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), _clientSkt);
    connectDone.WaitOne();

    if (_clientSkt.Connected)
    {
      // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
      _clientSkt.BeginReceive(_rx_buffer, 0, RX_BUFF_SIZE, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), _clientSkt);
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  protected void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
  {
    try
    {
      if (_clientSkt == null) return;

      // Read data from the client socket.
      int bytesRead = _clientSkt.EndReceive(ar);

      if (bytesRead > 0)
      {
        // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        Monitor.Enter(_clientSkt);
        _rx_stream.Write(_rx_buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        Monitor.Exit(_clientSkt);

        DecodeData(_rx_stream.ToArray());
      }

      _clientSkt.BeginReceive(_rx_buffer, 0, RX_BUFF_SIZE, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), _clientSkt);

    }
    catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException es)
    {
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I had something similar happen to me once, I spent ages trying to work out what was wrong until I eventually realized that my anti-virus software was blocking the connection. Have you checked for this?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the class `Socket` and not a higher level abstraction like [`TcpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing"? What code runs and what code does not run? Are there errors? You are just throwing all errors away. Don't do that.

Comment: If you see the tcp packets arriving then there is nothing wrong with this client code but maybe with the server code. Is it even running ? Do you see any reset signals or do you see only SYN's ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the anti virus and the firewall are disabled. With "nothing" I mean that the receive callback is not called. @PhilipStuyck how could be the server? It is always running...

Comment: How you you know the receive callback is not called? Breakpoint? Did you make sure the connection was established?

Comment: Based on the wireshark traces, the server is replying. But to which client ? You have to put some breakpoints and debug the code while you are testing it.

Comment: Could you please post the implementation of the Sender?

Comment: @Barzo, did you manage to solve this problem? I'm facing something similar